# Is it Possible to add list view in separate class in a android?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my application, I have created a separate class for `AsynchronousTask`. From the main class I execute the Asynchronous task class, is it possible to use the list view in Asynchronous task class?

**MAIN CLASS**

```
search_items_task = new Search_class();
search_items_task.execute(search_str);
```

**ASYNCHRONOUS TASK CLASS**

```
public class Search_class extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

JSONArray jsonarray;

String viewsubmenuSuccess;

//Activity activity;

ListView search_lv;

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response;

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.name.in/cakefoodnew/customer/submenus");

        post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
        post.setEntity(se);
        response = client.execute(post);

        // get a data
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String a = convertStreamToString(in);
        // Log.v("Search", ""+a);

        try {

            jsonarray = new JSONArray("[" + a + "]");
            json = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
            String menus = json.getString("submenus");
            viewsubmenuSuccess = json.getString("viewsubmenuSuccess");
            // Log.v("Search", ""+a);

            try {

                jsonarray = new JSONArray(menus);
                for (int ij = 0; ij < jsonarray.length(); ij++) {
                    json = jsonarray.getJSONObject(ij);
                    String name = json.getString("submenu");

                    if (name.toLowerCase().contains(params[0].toLowerCase())) {

                        String id = json.getString("submenu_id");
                        String price = json.getString("submenu_price");
                        String avaliable_quantity = json.getString("submenu_stock");

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(MENU_ID, id);
                        map.put(MENU_NAME, name);
                        map.put(MENU_PRICE, price);
                        map.put(MENU_STOCK, avaliable_quantity);
                        search_details.add(map);
                        //Log.v("search_details", ""+search_details);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return viewsubmenuSuccess;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if (viewsubmenuSuccess.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

        //search_lv = (ListView)activity.findViewById(R.id.search_list_view);
//Order_page_custom for customized list view
        /*Order_page_custom adapter = new Order_page_custom(activity,search_details);
        search_lv.setAdapter(adapter);*/

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Make a **Constructor** of `Search_Class` AsyncTask with `ListView` and `Context` parameter. Define `ListView` in `onCreate()` of Your activity after `setContentView()` and then Call AsyncTask..

Something Like;

```
Context mContext
ListView search_lv;

public Search_class(Context context, ListView list)
{
  mContext = context;
  search_lv = list;
}
```

Now in

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if (viewsubmenuSuccess.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {   
        Order_page_custom adapter = new Order_page_custom(mContext,search_details);
        search_lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

And in Main Class (Activity Class)

```
setContentView(R.layout.<activity_layout>);

search_lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.search_list_view);

search_items_task = new Search_class(this, search_lv);
search_items_task.execute(search_str);
```